# Create a count from baseline in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I'm looking to create an 'enumeration' variable starting from an entry that has a baseline flag. The enumeration only counts from 0 onward if the row has a 'Y' entry for BaseFlag for each subject and entry under 'Parameter'.

Here is the data:

```
Subject             Parameter              Visit                 BaseFlag
001                 Param1                 1                     
001                 Param1                 2                     Y
001                 Param1                 3                     
001                 Param1                 4                     
002                 Param1                 1                     Y
002                 Param1                 2                     
002                 Param1                 3                     
002                 Param2                 1                     Y
002                 Param2                 2
```

I'd like to have the following:

```
Subject             Parameter              Visit                 BaseFlag          Count
001                 Param1                 1                     
001                 Param1                 2                     Y                 0
001                 Param1                 3                                       1
001                 Param1                 4                                       2
002                 Param1                 1                     Y                 0
002                 Param1                 2                                       1
002                 Param1                 3                                       2
002                 Param2                 1                     Y                 0
002                 Param2                 2                                       1
```

Attempt:

```
proc sort data = data;
   by subject visit param;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   by subject visit param;
   retain count;
   if baseflag = 'Y' then count = 0;
   if first.subject then count + 1;
run;
```

Unfortunately this is not working.

Comment: I would expect to see `retain` somewhere.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - the [sum statement](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n1dfiqj146yi2cn1maeju9wo7ijs.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) strikes again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky. You are on the right track, but need to examine your BY statements. Actually, VISIT is subordinate to PARAM in this case.

Here is an example.

```
data have;
    subject='001'; param='Param1'; Visit=1; BaseFlag=' '; output;
    subject='001'; param='Param1'; Visit=2; BaseFlag='Y'; output;
    subject='001'; param='Param1'; Visit=3; BaseFlag=' '; output;
    subject='001'; param='Param1'; Visit=4; BaseFlag=' '; output;
    subject='002'; param='Param1'; Visit=1; BaseFlag='Y'; output;
    subject='002'; param='Param1'; Visit=2; BaseFlag=' '; output;
    subject='002'; param='Param1'; Visit=3; BaseFlag=' '; output;
    subject='002'; param='Param2'; Visit=1; BaseFlag='Y'; output;
    subject='002'; param='Param2'; Visit=2; BaseFlag=' '; output;
run;    

proc sort data = have;
   by subject param visit;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   by subject param visit;
   retain count .;
   if first.param then count=.;
   if baseflag = 'Y' then count = 0;
   else if count ne . then count + 1;
run;
```

[image]